# Simple app to automatically switch profiles - with toggle back afterwards

Tags: android, automation

I'd like to have a simple app that is:

1. Small
2. Free (at least for basic usage)
3. Provides a simple way to turn various phone settings (Vibration, WiFi, etc.) on and off, based on Conditions (Time, Location, etc.)
4. Automatically toggles the settings back afterwards (many automation apps  don't seem to do that)
5. I guess that's a nice-to-have point, but doesn't keep a constant icon in the notification area even when the app is closed (which it will be most of the time)

For example, turns the WiFi off during certain hours every day (which means after the time range the WiFi should be turned on automatically).

I'm currently using
[Smart Phone Lite](http://smartphone.bartinger.at/smart-phone-the-automatic-and-smart-settings-app/) ([at.bartinger.smartphonelite](https://apkpure.com/smart-phone-lite/at.bartinger.smartphonelite)) which does exactly this in just a 350Kb APK. Alas, it wasn't updated in a long time and was even removed from Google Play. Is there anything newer like it?

I've looked at the [automation+android tag combination](/questions/tagged/automation+android) but the relevant answers there are quite obsolete.

[image]

Comment: It's been a long time since I last looked on that (being a happy Tasker user, I saw no need any longer) – but be welcome to check my corresponding app listing: [Automation (Profile Switching and more)](https://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/tools_automation). With some luck it has an app you missed until now, and it even does what you need…

Comment: I'll take a look, thanks! But it's a very long list, divided to specific triggers, plus most dates there are from years ago.

Comment: Yeah, nothing I can do if the devs stop updating. The list updates itself automatically – but it cannot update the apps themselves… Several of them are quite up-to-date, but apps with a size below 1 MB are rare nowadays.